# PDF error while loading in react using ReactPDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to display a PDF file using the PdfReact component. While loading the PDF, I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: Ignoring invalid character "114" in hex strinpdf.worker.js:342 
Warning: Ignoring invalid character "34" in hex stringpdf.worker.js:342 
Warning: Ignoring invalid character "111" in hexstringpdf.worker.js:342
```

My setup looks like this:

```javascript
import React from 'react';
import ReactPDF from 'react-pdf/build/entry.webpack';

const About = () => {
   return (
    <div>
        <ReactPDF file="../pdf/Resume.pdf" />
    </div>
  )
}

export default About;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

I was not passing the pdf file as an object. That'a all that needed to happen for the PDF to render.